# 2D SR angle transformation

Tags: special-relativity

A couple of days ago I encountered a problem on special relativity. It said

> There are 2 observers A and B. B is emitting $k$ balls per unit time per unit angle from it in all directions from its perspective. The speed of those balls are $c=$ speed of light, and the B itself is moving with respect to A at a speed of $v$. A is observing B. Then how many balls B emit per unit angle per unit time as observed by A?

And this problem is in 2D so "angle" instead of "solid angle". To solve it I first transformed the velocity components of a ball emitted in angle $\varphi$ w.r.t. B's perspective. Magnitude will be same in any frame as the balls travel at speed of light.
$$
\begin{align}
v_x&=c\cos\varphi\\
v_y&=c\sin\varphi\\
\therefore\qquad
v_x^\prime&=\frac{c\cos\varphi-v}{       1-\frac{cv}{c^2}\cos\varphi }\\
v_y^\prime&=\frac{c\sin\varphi  }{\gamma(1-\frac{cv}{c^2}\cos\varphi)}
\end  {align}
$$
where $v_x^\prime$ and $v_y^\prime$ are the $x$ and $y$ component of the ball velocity for A and $\gamma$ is the usual gamma factor. If $\vartheta$ is the angle of the same ball from A's perspective then
$$\tan\vartheta=\frac{v_y^\prime}{v_x^\prime}=\frac{\sin\varphi}{\gamma(\cos\varphi-\frac vc)}$$
We can now apply chain rule:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm dn        }{\mathrm d\varphi  }&=k\\\therefore\qquad
\frac{\mathrm dn        }{\mathrm d\vartheta}\cdot
\frac{\mathrm d\vartheta}{\mathrm d\varphi  }&=k\\
\frac{\mathrm dn        }{\mathrm d\vartheta}&=k
\frac{\mathrm d\varphi  }{\mathrm d\vartheta}\\
&=\gamma k\frac{1-\frac vc\cos\varphi}{\sin^2\varphi+\gamma^2(\cos\varphi-\frac vc)^2}
\end  {align}
$$
where $n$ is the total number of balls per unit time. Moreover if $n$ balls are emitted from B's perspective in unit time then $n/\gamma$ will be emitted by B from A's perspective. So № of balls emitted by B per unit angle per unit time from A's perspective will be
$$=k\frac{1-\frac vc\cos\varphi}{\sin^2\varphi+\gamma^2(\cos\varphi-\frac vc)^2}$$
but the answer given in the book is different. Where am I wrong?

Comment: You really need to format this in LaTeX. It is pretty much impossible to read your question as it is.

Comment: Where is LaTeX?

Comment: OK fine I found a way to edit.

Comment: I see no fault in your calculations.

Comment: What did the book get?

Comment: Sorry I was looking at the wrong answer. There are no answers for long exercises